# How to Search through AWS Route53 Domain records through boto3 sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, amazon-route53

I want a webpage listing all the Records in a hosted zone from AWS Route 53 and use all the operations like Search, Add and Edit on those records.

Till now, I am able to list all the records using `list_resource_record_sets()`, also able to Add and Edit a record
using `change_resource_record_sets()`.

But the problem is with searching. I am **not able to find any parameter or function for Searching** through all the records and get all matching results. The searching should be like it is in AWS console.

How to implement this searching part?

Answer (score 1):

you already found it. It's the list_resource_records_sets

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ListResourceRecordSets.html

or boto:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.list_resource_record_sets

you can pass in additional arguments that narrow down what you are listing. Thisis what the console does.

```
response = client.list_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId='string',
    StartRecordName='string',
    StartRecordType='SOA'|'A'|'TXT'|'NS'|'CNAME'|'MX'|'NAPTR'|'PTR'|'SRV'|'SPF'|'AAAA'|'CAA'|'DS',
    StartRecordIdentifier='string',
    MaxItems='string'
)
```